# CSS hover div is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am working on one website so i have given `CSS div hover` effect on shopping cart link in the top menu...

Once you will add one product in the cart than `hover` it in the top menu on shopping cart link that `hover div` is not working properly when i hover that its come and sudden disappear not getting the exact bug....

So pls try to find out the bug.....

I am talking about this bug once u will see attached image... [image]

Here is the website link :- http://www.aurikjewels.com/index.php/

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post the relevant javascript/CSS. I'm 99% sure it's because there is a gap between the link and the popup so it stops showing.

Comment: its totally CSS based @danrhul you can see live site...

Comment: Because it's .button-show hover, when you are on 'header-items', the mouse is not over the button-show.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was `.button-show` do not have enough height to hold the event-hover.
Once the cursor moves away to gap between  `.button-show` and `#header-items`, the hover dies. 
and `#header-items` fades.

To overcome this problem, you have to do few things like

1. Add `padding-bottom: 10px;` to the `class="button-show"` as `inline style`
   The line will look like `<span class="button-show" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">`
2. Add background of `.block-cart-header .button-show` as `url(../images/shopping_bag.png) no-repeat right 1px`

Answer (score 0):

hover is not working as expected and dis-appears as you move out of the `header-items` because of the below property,

```
.block-cart-header #header-items
{
    padding:15px;
}
```

if you give `padding-top:0px;` and add `margin-top: -10px` this issue will not occur.

Comment: i have used padding for your hover div and i have tried your trick its not working.....

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-top: -10px;` to `header-items` div

Answer (score 0):

By simply moving the cart like so, into the button-show :

```
 <span class="button-show"><a href="http://www.aurikjewels.com/index.php/checkout/cart/?___SID=U">Shopping Cart</a>
    -   <div id="header-items">

             All cart informations                     
        </div><span class="price">Rs. 37,212.00</span>                     
 </span>
```

And adding a height to your button-show :

```
.block-cart-header .button-show {
background: url(../images/shopping_bag.png) no-repeat right center;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: right;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 5px 14px 0 0;
padding-right: 20px;
position: relative;
height: 24px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

this works for me !

Comment: its working but not exactly there is some dis-appearing issus check it with your trick....

Answer (score 0):

Hi all i have sorted out the issue....

I have **removed** the

```
.block-cart-header .actions { display:none !important; }
```

And now its working fine...

Thanks for all for your great support... :-)